# JSP is not rendering on Spring Boot version 2.7.15

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a Spring Boot application running on Java 17 with packaging type war, but it does not render the jsp pages.
Here is my pom.xml file regarding spring dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.44</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

MySpringApplication.java

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MySpringApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TomcatConfig.java

```java
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

DefaultController.java

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String renderJSP(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("in default controller");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

appplication.properties

```
server.port=8081

#jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.register-default-servlet=true
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a sample test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a cool test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The file structure is the following:

> appplication.properties file is located under src/main/java/resources
> test.jsp is located under src/main/webapp/WEB_INF.jsp

When running the app I get this log in the console

```
2023-09-07 12:10:54.087  INFO 6080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-07 12:10:54.098  INFO 6080 --- [           main] c.b.w.MySpringApplication           : Started MySpringApplication in 5.014 seconds (JVM running for 6.023)
Sep 07, 2023 12:11:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-07 12:11:34.463  INFO 6080 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-07 12:11:34.464  INFO 6080 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Completed initialization in 1 ms
in default controller
```

And I see this on localhost

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 07 12:59:15 EEST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

I saw that there are a lot of threads about this problem, but all the solutions provided there does not seem to fix my issues, any ideas or help on how to copre with this problem would be of great importance

Comment: JSP with embedded containers are severely limited, so I would not use them but use soemthing like thymeleaf instead. JSP will only work when you are using a war deployment and trying to make this work from an executable jar will not even work (an executable war should work).

Comment: But for now I am bounded to use JSP because I am doing a migration, so I need a jsp approach.

Comment: As stated it is limited and will only work with WAR packaging.

Comment: My project is packaged as war

Comment: You have to run the packaged war **not** the main method from your IDE as that won't work.

Comment: Here is my project which uses JSP with Spring Boot: https://github.com/scrhartley/jsp-streaming-poc/blob/master/pom.xml . I did find that for `tomcat-embed-jasper` and `jstl` it was difficult to decide whether to mark them as them provided or not. I think that if you're running the output war/jar by itself, it can't be provided (even the war that spring boot produces is also runnable as a jar by default), but if you are deploying it to a separate Tomcat, then it already has these JARs and you could potentially get conflicts if you include your own.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you said your config has

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
```

and:

> test.jsp is located under src/main/webapp/WEB_INF/jsp

I've noticed the hyphen in the config and the underscore in the folder. That will probably cause such an issue.